# What does the value 30 indicate in the type column in the MSrepl_commands table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-replication, transactional-replication

[Result Set of MSrepl_commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5zZd.png)

I want to infer that whether its a insert/update/delete command . We need to check at day end the amount of data replicated per article by the transactional replication. In the internet I am getting belwo result:

The `type` column in the `MSrepl_commands` table indicates the type of operation that the command represents. Here's what the different values mean:

- `1`: Insert operation
- `2`: Delete operation
- `4`: Update operation

So, if a row in the `MSrepl_commands` table has a `type` value of `1`, that means the command is an insert operation. Similarly, `2` represents a delete operation, and `4` represents an update operation.

Comment: From a quick Google 30 means "transactional replication command" - I assume this other list you have found is for some other replication type

Comment: I'll dare to be forward and say, "it's probably unknowable." Aside from little snippets [sp_MSget_repl_commands (Transact-SQL MetaData) Definition](https://pawjershauge.blogspot.com/2012/05/spmsgetreplcommands-transact-sql.html) mentioning that `MSrepl_commands.type` includes bit flags like `0x80000000` for snapshots, and `0x40000000` for post commands, there isn't much around to identify the > 100 commands that seem to have been used.

Comment: If your goal is "inserts/updates/deletes by article", couldn't you look at number of executions on the subscriber side for the stored procs associated with those operations? You currently have a tag of SQL 2005 on the question. Which, if true, I don't know what tools are even available (XE was introduced in SQL 2008 iirc). That said, what are you going to do once you have the counts you're looking for? "Hmm... inserts on table foobar look a little high". Then what?

Comment: @BenThul .. Its required by the management .

Comment: I'd encourage you to figure out what's behind the "requirement". If only for an opportunity to satisfy the requirement in another way. But, if you're fine with management telling you to pound sand and you just pound sand, it's your career.